# how to find instance region in azure application insights

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

we have multiple app service instances from different regions sending logs into the same application insights instance, and when looking at the logs for application insights i get the "cloud_RoleInstance" that shows the instance name, but i cant find what region that instance is located in.
So i am looking for a way to connect the specifik log entry to a region.

We are use the simple point and click connection, so we have not installed any agent on the instance.

I tried looking in the default logs for some field that mention it but havent found any thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `client_CountryOrRegion` to differ the region of each request.

Azure application insights look up the IP address (IPv4 or IPv6) of the web client to [calculate the region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/faq#how-are-city-countryregion-and-other-geo-location-data-calculated).

```
requests
| summarize sum(itemCount) by client_CountryOrRegion, bin(timestamp, 1m)
```

[image]

Comment: from my testing this only shows the connecting clients location, not the location of the server.

Comment: Per my searching, there's no properity in kusto query in azure app insights logs, so can you receive the solution that add app insights sdk into the program and send custom telemetry contains server location calculated by sever IP address?

Comment: i found the same, i even tried looking at the app service plan and i cant find any place where they refrence this, it feels like a major oversight not to log the region logs are comming from. 

we looked into using the SDK but the framework we are using dont work that well and implementing the SDK just to get the region feels wrong.

Comment: The reality is app insights doesn't provide your target property and your case doesn't support you to insert SDK. In my opinion, if you deploy your project on azure, you need to have a service plan first, and service plan decides the location/region where your app is running. In some terms, according to the request, developers may infer the server location. By the way, application insights is designed for logging or monitor, the server region maybe a rare used property in daily maintenance : )  If you feel my post is a bit of helpful, could you pls accept it as the answer? Thank you very much.

Comment: i disagree that region is rarly used, when you have an application that span multiple region it is a very valuable tool to see if the problem you are having is only in one region og spans multiple regions, if you do rolling updates it is even more importent so you can see if the regions with the newest version that is causing the problems, from what i can find out there is no way to find out what instance a region is a part of, and that is a major oversight, your anwser only shows what region a client is in and it would be misleading to mark is a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response and I think you may try to add a support ticket, refer to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request

Comment: Can I ask a question here? How you make the application span multiple region? Per my searching, azure app service seems not to support global distributing, you created several service plan? Or your deployment doesn't use azure app service?

Comment: we have multiple app services (one per region), reporting into the same application insight instance, to gather the logs one place.